# how to send transactional emails straight to inbox?

Tags: email, spam, inbox

I've been trying to send transactional emails to Gmail, Hotmail and Yahoo inboxes but most of the time they are going to spam folder.

I already tried using SPF, DKIM filter, multi-part message and still couldn't get the "magic solution" that always work.

If someone has experience on that, please share some tips and links about this.
I appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: What are "transactional emails"?

Answer (score 0):

Each provider will have it's own rules for creating emails that are not to be treated as spam and these will vary. I don't a simple one size fits all solution will exist.

Answer (score 0):

mhere is no dependable way to circumvent span filters. Spam evolves, counter measures evolve.

If you supply an email-based registration system the user will have an interaction with you as part of their email record. I would imagine the fact that they responded to an email from your domain may get you over the "spammy" threshold. Context is starting to count.